# Recommender system - Binary rating adding a condition

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-systems

I want to implement a recommender system based on collaborative filtering. Each user will have a set of visualized items (0-1's) and based on that similitude the recommendation will be generated.

In order to develop this, I was thinking of using the Jaccard similarity coefficient (if anyone has a better suggestion please let me know).

But, what if I want to add a condition to the result? For example, if the items are premium will appear first. This should be implemented at the end as a condition or there is another way?

To sum up, there are a set of items and some of them are premium and there are a set of user and each one have a set of visualized items. I want that the recommender system not only takes into account the visualizations but also that there are some items more "important" that has to appear firs (the premium ones).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The specification of the task is not clear to me.  Presumably, the answer will depend on the set of conditions that you might have to deal with, and how they will be represented.  There's a rich literature on collaborative filtering with many techniques, which are probably much more effective than Jaccard similarity (though I'm not clear on how you'd use Jaccard similarity, because the problem setup is unclear).

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I have a community of professors and they post different types of activities on the web page. I have to create a recommender system based on visualizations that suggest to them what activity is more probably gonna like them. As visualizations are binary (0-1's) I find that similarity measures are the best (maybe not, I am new at these). So, in the case some of them are "premium" their activities will be more visible in the recommendations (this is the conditional part).

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the question to provide all relevant context.  Please don't add clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question to read well and be self-contained, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  I still don't understand what you mean when you say you are using visualizations and then talk about metrics; which is it?  Are you going to make a recommendation based on the metric automatically, or is some human going to look at visualizations?